# How to make the "join" of an array of objects ids with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm facing some dificult to make this query with the MongoDB Aggregation Framrwork.

I have a order collection that has an array of objects ids from products example:

```
{
  _id: "5759b760aeacbfa420943d84",
  products: [
    "57718a2c9473f30ae88d1875",
    "57727d988d7e581809b454a1",
    "577bda7da756e2180507a944"
  ]
}
```

Here is an example of one document from my products ocllection:

```
{
  _id: "57718a2c9473f30ae88d1875",
  name: "Soap A"
}
```

How can I make an aggregation query in orders to get a list of contained products documents?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer you can't.
Aggregate works only on one collection.

However if you are using mongoose you can use query and '.populate' method

i.e

```
CollectionModel.find({}).populate('products').exec(function(err, items) {})
```

more details on populate http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

but that only applicable to nodejs application however language you are using have a look at some ORM frameworks for mongo

I hope that helps

Comment: But internally does Mongoose make another query to assemble that right?

Comment: @LeandroCurioso One way to get around this by either modifying Order model to include data that you need from product (de-normalize) and other one is to do lookups after aggregate is finished